# What is a "bernie"?

Tags: meaning

Proper nouns are not playable in Scrabble, but I know (from studying words) that "bernie" and "bernies" is playable in Scrabble.  But I cannot find a definition for the lowercase version anywhere online.

Help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently, in 1999, someone named Bernie Ecclestone tried to donate one million British pounds to the Labour Party, and since then, a "bernie" is a million pounds.

Comment: He's the owner of Formula 1. He donated 1M quid to the UK labour party who in a totally unrelated move then agreed to exclude F1 from the ban on cigarette advertising.

Comment: "An honest politician is one who, when he is bought, will stay bought."  -- Simon Cameron

Comment: even better in this case. The government had to return the money, but because there was no connection between the donation and the exemption, F1 kept it's cigarette advertising.

Comment: @MartinBeckett -- even better.  I feel like sending Bernie roses.  Or a check.

Answer (score 1):

*Bernie* is the corrected (or corrupted, depending on your outlook) spelling of the Old English word *byrnie*, which is a type of armor used by knights for the purpose of protecting the body when engaged in fighting with swords, lances, dirks, maces, pikes and/or other type of sharp, metal objects used to kill others.

Comment: Actually, it was not “Old English”.  The OED says of *byrnie* the following: *“Sc.* variant of ME. *brynie, brinie*, with metathesis of *r*. The word was thus brought nearer to OE. *byrne*, from which however it could not directly come, as this gave only the monosyllabic **byrn, burne, bryn.”*